# BCP Import error "Invalid character value for cast specification"

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

All 
I am using BCP for import export and getting "Invalid character value for cast specification" error for only 1(first row of export) row while trying to import back. 
Table Structure
Col1 -- Numeric(19,0)
Col2 -- NVARCHAR(400)
Col3 -- NVARCHAR(400)
I am using following commands

FOR Export

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT TOP 10 Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Server.dbo.TableName" queryout C:\Data\File.dat -S Server -T -t"<EOFD>" -r"<EORD>" -w'
```

Same way I am generating a FORMAT file

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP Server.dbo.TableName format nul -S Server -T -w -f "C:\Data\File.fmt" -t"<EOFD>" -r"<EORD>" '
```

Now when I try importing data back into SQL Server table I am getting error "**Invalid character value for cast specification**"
Error logs shows me something like this

```
#@ Row 1, Column 1: Invalid character value for cast specification @#

?1000   Mytestdataunicoded  nothing
```

Now from where this ? added in starting of my column data is still unknown.

I am able to import successfully when trying importing with format file, also able to import successfully when using switch -c, but for some purposes we must use -w switch to do that.

Comment: if you want to use -w , can you try removing the specified column and row delimeters?  i understood -w to use \n and \t by default.

Comment: But why it is not working in this case, when I explicitly declaring column and row delimeters

Comment: sorry, does -w work or not?  if it does, then maybe it is a requirement.  see the bcp.exe docs.

Comment: If I don't use this format file and try to insert it with the same options from which I exported data, it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using BCP for import export and getting "Invalid
> character value for cast specification" error for only 1(first row of
> export) row while trying to import back.

Does the first row of your export file contain column definition information?

If so, use -F2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#F

Answer (score 0):

When using -w option, I believe BCP ignores any -t or -r option and uses \t and \n and field and row terminators.

From MS docs:

> -w Performs the bulk copy operation using Unicode characters. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses nchar as the storage
>   type, no prefixes, \t (tab character) as the field separator, and \n
>   (newline character) as the row terminator. -w is not compatible with
>   -c.